# Compare strings with varying leading zeros in CRM 2011 using lambda

Tags: c#, lambda, dynamics-crm-2011

I'm trying to find all posts in CRM 2011 that have a reference number that matches a string.

The input string could have more or less leading zeros than the reference number in CRM.
This is the logic I want to achieve, ie leading zeros dont matter.

[image]

This was my initial thought:

```
var result = _serviceContext.dataSet
            .Where(x => x.reference.PadLeft(30, '0') == searchString.PadLeft(30, '0'))
```

Just add the same amount of zeros to both sides and were done.. This however is not an allowed operation when communicating with CRM 2011 using the SDK.

I'm not able to use long/integer parsing either, and substring seems to be forbidden too..

```
.Where(x => long.parse(x.reference) == long.parse(searchString))
```

Suggestions?

**EDIT**

This is how I have solved it for now. This is not a good solution as it first retrieves all the reference numbers to memory..

```
public dataItem GetFromReferenceNumberTest(string referenceNumber)
{
    var allOfThem = _serviceContext.dataSet
                .Where(x => x.reference != null)
                .Select(x => new
                {
                    id = x.Id,
                    reference = x.reference,
                })
                .ToList(); // this forces a get of all 40k posts

    var match = allOfThem 
        .Where(x => x.reference.PadLeft(30, '0') == referenceNumber.PadLeft(30, '0'))
        .Single();

    return  _serviceContext.dataSet.Where(x => x.Id == match.id).Single();
}
```

This works because I am using .ToList() on the first query and that makes lambda retrieve all the items locally, and then I can use all the functionality I want to.

Comment: In response to your answer, why not start with a contains condition to at least narrow down your dataset?

Answer (score 0):

Probably a better way but here is a quick and dirty solution:

```
string s = "01234";
string subStr = string.Empty;
char[] charArr = new[] { '1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9' };

if (s.StartsWith("0"))
{
     int x = s.IndexOfAny(charArr, 0);
     subStr = s.Substring(x);
}

Console.Write(subStr);
```

Will trim all leading zeros. Where `s` could be the CRM ref num you would compare with the input string.

Comment: If I'm not missunderstanding I can't do this without retrieveing the entire dataset, and that is around 40000 posts.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using FetchXml very easily using an Ends-With search. To avoid 11234, try adding a not ends with.

```
<fetch version="1.0" output-format="xml-platform" mapping="logical" distinct="false">
  <entity name="contact">
    <filter type="and">
      <condition attribute="fullname" operator="not-like" value="%11234" />
      <condition attribute="fullname" operator="like" value="%1234" />
    </filter>
  </entity>
</fetch>
```

Perhaps you could either use this, or find the equivalent for the early bound entities.

Comment: This would match 1234 with 1111234.

Comment: If that's a problem you should put it in your question. Perhaps if that brings back an acceptably low number of results, you could filter client side?

Comment: @JensBerfenfeldt see my edit I think that should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to use a function returning an expression, like in this post: [combining a function or extension method with linq](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20216651/problems-combining-a-function-or-extension-method-with-linq-to-match-aliases)

Comment: I'll try it out but I will be surprised if this works with CRM 2011.